# Set HighChart yAxis's min max to a specific series only

Tags: javascript, highcharts, candlestick-chart

I have a stock price candlestick series And a line series that share yAxis with the candlestick series. By default, the API automatically set chart's yAxis range to the min/max of two series's min/max(candlestick series, line series)

But I want to show the candlestick series more importantly than line chart. So, chart's yAxis min/max should be limited only the candlestick series even if it cut the line series off.

And the yAxis min/max should be adjusted when the chart is scrolled dynamically.

How can I do that?

[jsfiddle simple code](https://jsfiddle.net/vad58wer/23/)

```js
var chartData = [
  [1473687000000, 102.65, 105.72, 102.53, 105.44],
  [1473773400000, 107.51, 108.79, 107.24, 107.95],
  [1473859800000, 108.73, 113.03,  108.6, 111.77],
  [1473946200000, 113.86, 115.73, 113.49, 115.57]
];
    
var avgData = [
  [1473687000000, 250],
  [1473773400000, 300],
  [1473859800000, 280],
  [1473946200000, 290]
];

$(function() {
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    // title: {text: '---'},
    rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [
        // { type: 'hour', count: 1, text: '1h' },
        { type: 'day', count: 1, text: '1d' },
        // { type: 'all', count: 1, text: 'All' }
      ],
      selected: 1,
      //inputEnabled: true
    },
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'datetime',
    
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
      },
      title: {text: 'OHLC'},
      height: '100%',
      lineWidth: 2,
      resize: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }], 

    plotOptions: {
      candlestick: {
        downColor: 'blue',
        upColor: 'red',
        dataGrouping: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'ohlc',
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: chartData,
    }, {
      name: 'avg',
      type: 'line',
      data: avgData,
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
dic#container {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: could you add the script in question, together with a little sample data?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added a jsfiddle link and simplfied data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'afterDrawChartBox' event, you can use `setExtremes` method with min and max values from `candlestick` series:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, 'afterDrawChartBox', function(e) {
    var candlestick = this.series[0];
    this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(candlestick.dataMin, candlestick.dataMax, true, false);
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/520km1wv/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes