# How to reduce HighStock chart gap between candles?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using candlestick chart of HighChart-HighStock. I want to reduce the gap between candlesticks. It's not so bad when it's on a wide range zoom. But when I zoomed the chart a lot, the padding between candle makes me annoyed because they are too wide apart.

I tried setting `pointPadding` of `plotOption&xAxis` to `0`, but nothing happened. How can I shrink this gap?

Zoomed chart - too wide gap between candlestick

[image]

Wide view chart - not so bad

[image]

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  // title: { text: '---'},
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [
      // { type: 'hour', count: 1, text: '1h' },
      {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d'
      },
      // { type: 'all', count: 1, text: 'All' }
    ],
    selected: 1,
    //inputEnabled: true
  },
  xAxis: [{
    pointPadding: 0,
    type: 'datetime',

  }, {
    type: 'datetime',
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: 'OHLC'
    },
    height: '70%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    resize: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }, {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Volume'
    },
    top: '75%',
    height: '25%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      downColor: 'blue',
      upColor: 'red',
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    },
    line: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
      name: 'ohlc',
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: chartData,
    },
    {
      name: 'avg5',
      type: 'line',
      data: avg5Data,
      color: '#FF0000',
    },
    {
      name: 'avg10',
      type: 'line',
      data: avg10Data,
      color: '#0C9B3A',
    },
    {
      name: 'avg20',
      type: 'line',
      data: avg20Data,
      color: '#FF9900',
    },
    {
      name: 'avg60',
      type: 'line',
      data: avg60Data,
      color: '#000000',
    },
    {
      name: 'vol',
      type: 'column',
      data: moneyData,
      yAxis: 1,
      color: '#0944a3',
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    }
  ],
});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HighChart yAxis's min max to a specific series only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241437/set-highchart-yaxiss-min-max-to-a-specific-series-only)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, It's perfectly different question that you said. What's the matter with you? What am I doing wrong with stackoverflow rule? You angry cuz I didnt' accept your answer in my previous question? It's frustrating...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ...instead you call me a `troll` in your question, which is nothing be a `projection`. cheap mind tricks do not impress me.

Comment: @MartinZeitler earnestly your answer was very kind and thanks a lot that. but that not helped me solve the problem. I didn't want detour solution like divided chart. In this situation, accepting only one answer is right? I thought I can wait more answer to find than fit my problem.

Comment: you did not read the whole answer then and if you cannot script JS, this is not exactly my fault - will certainly not answer anymore of your questions, nor queries. good bye.

Comment: Really? I read all your answer and didn't solve my problem. What a tough situation.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181131

Comment: Why did you remove all your answers we talked in previous question?

Comment: because you've moved on to create a quite similar question instead of trying to bind the `yAxis.events` to set the `xAxis.max`... and this question here likely also has to do with events - while you could have at least used the `code snippet` provided - instead of screenshots, which one can neither copy/paste nor test... without the least sample data it is impossible to tell why something is charted alike it is being charted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `series.pointPadding` combined with `series.groupPadding` (equal to zero) to achieve the expected effect. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahxrk5zq/

```
    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: data,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0.04,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: [
                [
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
```

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.groupPadding

Comment: It works just what I wanted. thanks! I did it to plotOptions-candlestick section and works nicely.